# Popup panel in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, windows-phone

I'd like to create a control, which behaves similarly to the Windows Phone's keyboard button. When user taps and holds the control, it should expand to show additional options.

Though I generally know, how to implement this control, I have no idea on how to display a panel, which will exceed the boundaries of the control. If there is a way to achieve this effect in Windows Phone (and should be - the keyboard is being displayed this way), how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Popup control to your control and show it by setting the Popup's IsOpen property to true. The Popup can show outside of the control's context. Here's a really cheesy UserControl which shows its Popup on Hold:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PhoneApp48.WindowsPhoneControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"
    Hold="UserControl_Hold">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" Fill="Yellow" />
        <Popup x:Name="myPopup" IsOpen="False">
            <StackPanel Width="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=ActualWidth}" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}">
                 <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." />
                 <Button Click="Button_Click">Close</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code:

```
private void UserControl_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    myPopup.IsOpen = true;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myPopup.IsOpen = false;
}
```